# Removing duplicates and selecting distinct values with struct array in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm getting started with BigQuery. I have a database that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvwY9.png)
which can be generated as

```
    WITH T AS (
  SELECT 0 AS id, 'red' AS colour, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING>>[(2, "dot"), (2, "dot"), (1, "string")] AS arr, DATE(2020,01,31) AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 0 AS id, 'red' AS colour, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING>>[(2, "dot"), (2, "dot"), (1, "string")] AS arr, DATE(2020,01,31) AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 0 AS id, 'red' AS colour, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING>>[(20, "dot"), (20, "dot"), (1, "string")] AS arr, DATE(2020,01,30) AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 0 AS id, 'black' AS colour, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING>>[(296, "dot"), (212, "plane"), (156, "cube")] AS arr, DATE(2020,01,31) AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 0 AS id, 'black' AS colour, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING>>[(296, "dot"), (212, "plane"), (156, "cube")] AS arr, DATE(2020,01,31) AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 0 AS id, 'black' AS colour, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING>>[(296, "dot"), (21, "plane"), (156, "cube")] AS arr, DATE(2020,01,30) AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 0 AS id, 'black' AS colour, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING>>[(296, "dot"), (2, "plane"), (156, "cube")] AS arr, DATE(2020,01,30) AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'blue' AS colour, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING>>[(4, "cube"), (4, "cube"), (4, "cube")], DATE(2020, 01, 31) AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'orange' AS colour, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING>>[(5, "string")], DATE(2020,01,31) AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'orange' AS colour, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING>>[(5, "string")], DATE(2020,01,30) AS date
)
SELECT *
FROM T;
```

I want to select each distinct date, and for each date take each shape and maximum count for each id and each colour. For example for 2020-01-31 for red 0 it'd be 2 dot 1 string, for 2020-01-30 for 0 black it'd be 296 dot 21 plane 156 cube. There may be repetition in rows, in dates and within the struct array in the data.

More precisely, I'd like the result of the query to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6jGc.png)
, which can be generated by

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT DATE(2020,01,31) AS date, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING, id INT64, colour STRING>>[(2, "dot", 0, "red"), (1, "string", 0, "red"), (296, "dot", 0, "black"), (212, "plane", 0, "black"), (156, "cube", 0, "black"), (4, "cube", 1, "blue"), (5, "string", 2, "orange")] AS res UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE(2020,01,30) AS date, ARRAY<STRUCT<count INT64, shape STRING, id INT64, colour STRING>>[(20, "dot", 0, "red"), (1, "string", 0, "red"), (296, "dot", 0, "black"), (21, "plane", 0, "black"), (156, "cube", 0, "black"), (5, "string", 2, "orange")] AS res
)
SELECT *
FROM T;
```

I'm struggling with two issues: removing duplicates and selecting id and shape for each row of the array. For instance the query

```
SELECT date, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(ARRAY((SELECT AS STRUCT MAX(count), shape FROM UNNEST(arr) GROUP BY shape)))
FROM T
GROUP BY date
```

returns me duplicates. And then I'd need to assign to each nested row the id and colour. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with T AS (),
unnested_and_unique as (
  select distinct id, colour, count, shape, date
  from T left join unnest(arr) x
)
select date,array_agg(struct(count,shape,id,colour)) as res
from unnested_and_unique
group by 1
```

Comment: oh silly me, I was cross joining! Thank you for your answer